# mysqld got exception 0xc0000005

Tags: mysql, crash, mysql-workbench

Sorry my english is not fluent. I am a newbie in MySQL database. I use MySQL 8.0.30 on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter. I have problem that MySQL crashes frequently (the MySQL service stops) always with same error log. I've tried to find the source of the problem but it's not resolved.

For the information I used Grafana Web Server and MySQL on same device with the following specs:
Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4208 CPU @ 2.10GHz   2.10 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.6 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Please give me an advice to resolve this trouble.
Thanks before

Here is the error MySQL log details :

```
10:01:25 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ffa8ac5b496    jemalloc.dll!???
7ffa8ac5b918    jemalloc.dll!???
7ffa8ac5ef91    jemalloc.dll!je_realloc()
7ffa82547ddd    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffa8258bcea    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffa8258e7e3    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffa8255956d    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffa8246263c    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffa826092ff    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll!CRYPTO_memcmp()
7ffab7d47167    ntdll.dll!RtlActivateActivationContextUnsafeFast()
7ffab7d4848a    ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownThread()
7ffab7d28bae    ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserThread()
7ffab5851b8a    KERNELBASE.dll!FreeLibraryAndExitThread()
7ffab55c6c5d    ucrtbase.dll!_recalloc()
7ffab55f3c19    ucrtbase.dll!_endthreadex()
7ff682fc4605    mysqld.exe!?modify_thread_cache_size@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXK@Z()
7ff6844987a9    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z() [truncated, 260 bytes total]
7ff68405139c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_self_setname@@YAXPEBD@Z()
7ffab55c6b4c    ucrtbase.dll!_recalloc()
7ffab7274ed0    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffab7d9e44b    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I have tried reducing the data read and written, then increasing the client connection limit

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 1 hour UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) last 500 lines of your error log, please 
I) your complete my.cnf 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: There are not any SSD or NVME on the server.
Here is link for additional DB information you asked for https://justpaste.it/95oqm

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section to possibly avoid unplanned shutdowns.

```
innodb_thread_concurrency=10  # from 33 for reasonable limit for your 16 available total threads 
innodb_redo_log_capacity=96M  # from innodb_log_file_size name and 48M limit
```

****    this is current name rather then deprecated innodb_log_file_size per error log

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 124M for about 1/2 available RAM to reduce innodb_data_reads RPS of 31.
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 63,041
thread_cache_size=128  # from 10 to reduce threads_created RPS of ~ 5
```

Please view profile for contact info.  You have many opportunities to improve performance with additional Global Variable changes.

Would like to hear your story of how you get this much activity in 96 seconds of uptime.  :)